# Common Canopy install no gui setup problematic

Tags: python, enthought

I am trying to install Canopy for a shared system I followed the instructions here https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469200 but now when I run:

```
    $ ./canopy_cli --no-gui-setup --common-install --install-dir=/usr/local
```

I get

```
    __boot__.py: cannot connect to X server
```

I remove locations.cfg and my .canopy directory each time.
I did however initially make the mistake of running it as root earlier (which worked and did not complain about X) I removed the Canopy and .canopy folders as well as the install in /usr/local/Canopy_64.
Did I miss something somewhere? I do not have X installed on the server and I would like to complete it without the GUI.

Comment: what version of Canopy? The current version is 1.5.5. To update Canopy to the latest version, please see https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website

Comment: Its a fresh download from the site so it is 1.5.5, yes. A machine restart did not help either.